# Enable 256 colors in Konsole (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, colors, konsole

I would like to enable 256 colors in Konsole but I didn't get it working the right way. I have set in my enviroment:

`TERM=xterm-256color`

```
$ tput colors
256
```

But the colortest of [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell) always prints colors 17-21 in blue.

What am I missing to get 256 colors working?

Answer (score 1):

These extra colors swatch can't currently be set, as described in this Konsole bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344181